# Пару вопросов по поводу vue.js

Tags: vue.js

я недавно стал пробовать писать на vue.js. У меня есть два вопроса, которые я бы хотел спросить у более опытных людей.

1. Например, у меня есть `parent` компонент, который включает в себя кучу `child` компонентов, скажем всякие радио, чекбоксы, таблицы, кнопки.  Должна ли быть логика во вложенных компонентах? Или они должны сообщить основному компоненту, что произошло событие и он должен отработать его?
2. Еще вопрос, по поводу пробрасывания значений между компонентами. Не трудно пробросить переменную в `child` компонент из `parent`, но чтобы узнать из `parent`, что значение было изменено в `child`, делают `$emit` или привязку `v-model`. У меня возникли большие трудности, когда я создавал свой кастомный компонент `select`, и нужно было связать выбранное значение через `v-model` чтобы в `parent` компоненте всегда было выбранное значение. Могу ли я в качестве значений использовать не простые переменные, а объекты, ведь они передаются по ссылке.Например, вместо того, чтобы передать в `child` компонент такое `myProperty: 10` , я бы мог передать такое `myProperty: {value:10}` , и это бы избавило меня от необходимости использовать `v-model` и `$emit`. Видел такое решение где-то, но оно было заминусовано.

Comment: передача объектов в пропсы компонентов - нормальная практика, просто используй `Object.assign({}, objectFromProps)`.